Error in automatic derivative calculation with pytorch
x2=torch.tensor(x,requires_grad=True)
t2=torch.tensor(t,requires_grad=True)
def mr():
            for k in range(n):
                z01=solve_burgers(torch.tensor([x2[k]]),0.25,0.01/np.pi)[0]
                z01.backward(retain_graph=True)
                u_xr=x2.grad[k]
                u_tr=t2.grad[k]
            return u_xr,u_tr,u_xxr

solve_burgers is a function to solve burger equation.
When I run this code to calculate derivatives, I get the following error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

How can I fix the error?
def solve_burgers(X, t, nu):
def f(y):
 return np.exp(-np.cos(np.pi * y) / (2 * np.pi * nu))
def g(y):
 return np.exp(-(y**2) / (4 * nu * t))
def fun(eta):
  return torch.sin(torch.pi * (x - eta)) * f(x - eta) * g(eta)
def fun1(eta):
  return f(x - eta) * g(eta)
U = torch.zeros_like(X)
for i in range(len(X)):
 x = X[[[i]]]
 uxt = -quad(fun, -torch.inf, torch.inf)[0]
 uxt2=torch.tensor(uxt,requires_grad=True)
 uxt30=quad(fun1, -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
 uxt3=torch.tensor(uxt30,requires_grad=True)
 U[i] = uxt2 / uxt3
return U


The problem seems to be in numerical solution of solve_burgers(), which you need to carefully verify:
import torch
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad


def solve_burgers(X, t, nu):
    f = lambda y: np.exp(-np.cos(np.pi * y) / (2 * np.pi * nu))
    g = lambda y: np.exp(-(y ** 2) / (4 * nu * t))
    numer = lambda eta: torch.sin(torch.pi * (X - eta)) * f(X - eta) * g(eta)
    denom = lambda eta: f(X - eta) * g(eta)

    uxt, _ = quad(lambda eta: -numer(eta).item(), -np.inf, np.inf)
    uxt3, _ = quad(lambda eta: denom(eta).item(), -np.inf, np.inf)

    return -uxt / uxt3


def mr(x2):
    u_xr = []
    for k in range(len(x2)):
        z01 = solve_burgers(x2[k], 0.25, 0.01 / np.pi)
        u_xr.append(z01)
    return u_xr


x2 = torch.tensor([10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
print(mr(x2))


Prints
[4.01485673240222e-06, 8.861857759474245e-06, 1.0083838264149217e-05, 4.01485673240222e-06, 8.861857759474245e-06, 1.0083838264149217e-05]

Note

Make sure your equations are correct.


The answer is still NAN...

I do not receive an error. yes sure

equations are correct. @user24714692

@OrfeoTerkuci The issue has not been resolved yet. Only the error was handled, we did not look for error handling
